# Do I need to uninstall older version of JDK 7.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

all I have installed both `JDK 1.7 update 21`(1.7.0.210) and `51`(1.7.0.510), and so I wonder do I need to uninstall the older version which is `JDK 1.7 update 21`, as they both show up in the list of `Programs and Features` on Windows. Second, I tried Java Uninstall Tool, it only reports `There are no older versions of Java on your computer`. So I wonder can I just use the `Programs and Features` that manually uninstall any version of Java if I need to.

Another question is that I am using `Eclipse` doing `Java` and `Android` programming, so I wonder if I remove the older version of `Java`, will it affect the compiler settings in `Eclipse`, since `Eclipse` is kinda automatically detects your `JDK` versions and hence sets `Compiler compliance level` in `Preferences`.

cheers

Comment: Answer to title question: **probably not.** If you're using just eclipse, it should automatically use latest java version, but you can also change it if you wish. If you're running commands from command line tool (cmd or terminal), check which one is set in your path. The reason why every update is separate is maybe so you can remove only the version you wish (I don't know why one would want to do this) or it's a result of lazy programmer(s), so they made a new installer for every new version instead of updating an existing one. I might be wrong on this, this didn't really bother me.

Comment: @maremp I set `JAVA_HOME` to `jdk1.7.0_21` in order to install `Android Developer Toolkit (ADT)`(coz there was difficulty when I tried to install the `ADT`). So I wonder do I need to update `JAVA_HOME` to `jdk1.7.0_51`?

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt, but on the other hand, these versions contain just some minor fixes. The features of JDK 7 will be the same, regardless of which update you're using.

Comment: @maremp I just downloaded Java 8. Will eclipse automatically recognize it?

Comment: For new projects: yes (at least it did when I tried). But I don't know how it'll behave for existing projects, you'll probably have to change it in project settings.